# monter, surmonter, remonter en compétence!

Tags: expressions

Comment on pourrait exprimer le fait que quelqu’un veut améliorer ses compétences. J'ai trouvé dans mes lectures les trois termes mentionnés au niveau du titre, j'aimerais savoir la différence entre les trois ;  merci pour tout sorte de retour.

Comment: démonter aussi ?

Comment: Merci LPH ..Non démonter ca se voit c'est dans le sens négative..mais franchement dans pas ml de contextes j’étends les 3 termes afin d’exprimer que la personne à passer vers un autre niveau supérieur

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Monter*** est neutre. Il signifier simplement aller vers le haut. C'est couramment utilisé dans l'expression *monter en compétence(s)*, expression faisant partie du jargon des entreprises qui signifie acquérir de nouvelles compétences ou améliorer les existantes.

***Surmonter*** signifie passer au dessus d'un obstacle, dominer une difficulté. Ce verbe ne peut pas être utilisé avec *compétence* (<s>*surmonter en compétence*</s>). On pourra cependant dire: *Pour que tu puisses monter en compétences, il faudra surmonter ton appréhension à reprendre tes études.*

***Remonter*** signifie que l'on va vers le haut après avoir fait l'inverse. *Remonter en compétence(s)* signifie donc se remettre à niveau dans un ou plusieurs domaines où l'on avait perdu de son expérience.

Comment: Oh merci beaucoup @jlligare arès serait t-il possiblede me donner deux exemples ou on pourrait utiliser **Surmenter**

Answer (score 1):

The idea of going up, figuratively, is found in all three words; however, as concerns someone's competence, they are not proper. A term you can use without any modifier added is « **rehausser** » ; it's a verb that carries a little ambiguity, though ; one is not quite sure whether it means « get back to a former level that was higher » or « improve on the présent level » ; a context is necessary for that to be clear when you speak (or write).

- Pour rehausser ses compétences on suit généralement des cours ou on participe à des stages de formation.

If you absolutely want to use « **remonter** » a modifier is necessary, such as « niveau » ; this is not nevertheless the most idiomatic way of saying that, it's merely acceptable. There is not the problem that « rehausser » implies: it means only « to get back to a former level or to a level approaching that level, after a drop from it has resulted.

- Je voudrais remonter le niveau de mes compétences.

More usual is the use of a verb such as « **accroitre** » and « **augmenter** ».

- Je voudrais augmenter ma compétence. (*ou* mon niveau de compétence)
- Je voudrais accroitre ma compétence dans ce domaine. (*ou* mon niveau de compétence)